# How to grep a String in all the java files in subdirectories?

Tags: regex, string, grep

I want to use `grep` to find the lines contain `String` in all java files under current directory.

I tried:

```
grep -r "String" **/*.java
```

But it doesn't work:

```
grep : **/*.java:  no such file or directory
```

How to write it?

---

**UPDATE**

I'm on windows, using the `grep` provided by `unxUtils`, which doesn't support `--include` parameter. Is there any other way?

Comment: For **`Windows`**, I recommend a program called [AstroGrep](http://astrogrep.sourceforge.net/) on [SourceForge](http://astrogrep.sourceforge.net/) ... it is GUI based and the default tick-box is "Search subfolders".  I like it so much I just wish there was in equivalent on my Linux box ... ~sigh~

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Use recursive grep:

```
grep -r "String" --include=*.java .
```

Comment: thank you. I found it works on linux, but now I'm on windows. Is there any other way?

Comment: If you have cygwin installed same command will work on Windows as well, I have actually tried on my cygwin and it worked fine on Windows 7 as well.

Comment: ..or gitbash, as it has amounts of executable useful and full support of Windows path.

Answer (score 8):

I guess the `unxUtils` provide the `find` utility. So you could try to do:

```
find . -name "*.java" -exec grep "String" {} \;
```

or

```
find . -name "*.java" -exec grep "String" {} \+
```

The first version will execute one `grep` command for each file found. The latter version will only execute as many `grep` commands as necessary but not every `find` version supports the `+` argument.

Comment: The bad news is `find . -name "*.java"` doesn't work for `fild` of `unxUtils`, it reports `File not found - *.java`. Finally, I just installed the `cygwin`

Comment: It might be helpful to add a filename as part of the search to make it easier.  The print argument will help here:find . -name "*.java" -print -exec grep "String" {} \;

Answer (score 0):

This is working fine.

```
find . -iname "*.java" -exec grep "String" {} +;
```

`-exec` executes the command on each file found.

`{}` represents the file names found by `find`, and `+` tells `find` to execute `grep` with as many files as possible (to improve efficiency).